# Apply series of patches using specific patch number

Tags: git, github, gitlab, patch, git-am

I have set of patches, for e.g as below.

```
0001-first-commit.patch
0002-second-commit.patch
0003-third-commit.patch
0004-4th-commit.patch
0005-fifth-commit.patch
```

What is the best way to apply patches from given patch number up to end. I mean can we specify 'range' while applying patch using **git am**?

For example, I want to apply patch from 0003 up to 0005. What flag with **git am** should I use? Is there any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply 0003 to 0005,

```
git am 000[3-5]*.patch
```

To skip 0001 and 0004,

```
git am 000[!14]*.patch
```

For more complicated situations, you may need a small script like a loop.